# Consuming WCF service with Jquery Mobile is returning a 400 bad request

Tags: .net, ajax, wcf, jquery

I've searched for this and I've not been able to find something that helps me so I appologise if this has been posted and I've just been unable to find it.

I've created a WCF service application that is being hosted in IIS. Presently its very basic with just a hello world method basically to return a country name and its code as a json object.

I've also written some jquery that will call the method remotely with the aim of populating list objects.

Currently when I call the method it hits the success paramater of the ajax call and alerts me with "undefined" I've no idea whats causing this but its most likely I've made a silly mistake.

Heres the code of the service and jquery

web config:

```
<configuration>

<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
<authentication mode="None" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
<standardEndpoints>
  <webScriptEndpoint>
    <standardEndpoint crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true"/>
  </webScriptEndpoint>
 </standardEndpoints>

</system.serviceModel>


</configuration>
```

service1.svc

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="RestfulFlightWCF.Service1" codeBehind="Service1.svc.cs" Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebScriptServiceHostFactory"  %>
```

service1.svc.cs
    {
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "JsonpAjaxService")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class Service1 
{
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public Country GetCountry(string id)
    {

       Country county = new Country();
        county.Name = "United Kingdom";
        county.Id = "gb";
        return county;
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Country
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

}
```

jquery

```
    $(document).ready(
     function () {
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            Data:'gb',
            Url:"http://192.168.1.6:80/FlightServices.svc/GetCountry",
            DataType:"jsonp",
            method:"GetCountry",
            success: function(msg){
                debugger;
                    alert(msg.responseText);
                        if (msg.responseText) {
                            var err = msg.responseText;
                            if (err)
                                error(err);
                            else
                                error({ Message: "Unknown server error." })
                        }
            },
            failure: function(){
                alert("something went wrong");
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("something happned");
            }
        });
         });
```

Sorry for the long post but I thought it would help if I included my code.

Comment: Look's like you are not serializing your data to json

Comment: probably a stupid question but I'm tired and can't think straight. Is that in the ajax call or in the wcf service that I would have to serialize it?

Comment: Before you return county , you need to serialize it into json...

Comment: It's still coming back as undefined if i change the method to return jsonSerializer.Seralize(Country) :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok So I got this working tonight after fiddling about for a while so I thought I'd post up some of the stuff that I found out whilst looking for the fix.

1. Add in response format to the WebGet on the method being called.

   ```
   [WebGet(ResponseFormat= WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
   ```
2. Changed my jQuery to the following:

   ```
   var Type;
   var Url;
   var Data;
   var ContentType;
   var DataType;
   var ProcessData;
   var method;
   //Generic function to call WCF  Service
   function CallService() {
       $.ajax({
           type: Type, //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
           url: Url, // Location of the service
           data: Data, //Data sent to server
           contentType: ContentType, // content type sent to server
           dataType: DataType, //Expected data format from server
           processdata: ProcessData, //True or False
           success: function (msg) {//On Successful service call
               ServiceSucceeded(msg);
           },
           error: ServiceFailed// When Service call fails
       });
   }

   function ServiceFailed(xhr) {
       alert(xhr.responseText);
       if (xhr.responseText) {
           var err = xhr.responseText;
           if (err)
               error(err);
           else
               error({ Message: "Unknown server error." })
       }
       return;
   }

   function ServiceSucceeded(result) {
       if (DataType == "jsonp") {

               debugger;
               resultObject = result.GetEmployeeResult;
               var string = result.Name + " \n " + result.Id ;
               alert(string); 
       }
   }

   function GetCountry() {
       Data = {id : "us"};
       Type = "GET";
       Url = "http://192.168.1.6:80/FlightService.svc/GetCountry"; 
       DataType = "jsonp";
       ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
       ProcessData = false;
       method = "GetCountry";
       CallService();
   }

   $(document).ready(
    function () {

        GetCountry();
    }
   ```

key point I found was passing the parameters down to the webGet method as

```
data: {id : "gb"}
```

Answer (score 0):

A small sample of how it has to be sent back

```
public string GetCountry(string id)
    {
        string json = string.Empty;
        Country county = new Country();
        county.Name = "United Kingdom";
        county.Id = "gb";
        json = "{ \"name\" : \"" + county.Name + "\", \"id\" : \"" + county.Id + "\" }"
        return json;
    }​
```

Hard Coding is a bad practice . Better to serialize the data.

Comment: I tried it with the JavaScriptSeriliazer and it still returns null, for some reason when looking at the msg variable when debugging the jquery it just contains the entire javascript instead of a a json object, makes me think I'm doing something wrong with the jquery now

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might be missing some configuration from the xml config including:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior>
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      </behavior>  
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors> 
<system.serviceModel>
```

Don't really use WCF myself but run through this tutorial and it should cover whats missing:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/417629/Support-for-JSONP-in-WCF-REST-services

Comment: Didn't seem to work, seriously considering giving up on WCF now